# Exclude certain line depending on a certain condition in t-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Firstly, I have created the following stock sales SELECT statement:

```
SELECT
PostST.TxDate AS TxDate,
PostST.Reference AS InvNum,
Client.Name AS CustomerName,
SalesRep.Code AS SalesRep,
WhseMst.Code AS Whse,
CONCAT (StkItem.Description_1, ' - ',StkItem.Code) AS Item,
_etblLotTracking.cLotDescription AS LotNumber,
CASE 
    WHEN PostST.TrCodeID = 34 THEN (PostST.Quantity * 1)
    WHEN PostST.TrCodeID = 30 THEN (PostST.Quantity * -1)
    ELSE 0 
    END AS QtySold,
CAST 
    (
CASE
    WHEN PostST.TrCodeID = 34 THEN (PostST.Credit / PostST.Quantity)
    WHEN PostST.TrCodeID = 30 THEN (PostST.Debit / (PostST.Quantity * -1))
    ELSE 0
    END 
    as [money] 
    )
    AS CustomerPrice,
StkItem.ItemGroup AS ItemGroup,
StkItem.ulIIStockType AS StockType, 
YEAR (PostST.TxDate) AS Year,
DATENAME (MONTH, (PostST.TxDate)) AS Month

FROM 
PostST
INNER JOIN StkItem
    ON StkItem.StockLink = PostST.AccountLink
INNER JOIN PostAR
    ON PostAR.cAuditNumber = PostST.cAuditNumber
INNER JOIN Client
    ON Client.DCLink = PostAR.AccountLink
INNER JOIN SalesRep
    ON SalesRep.idSalesRep = PostAR.RepID
INNER JOIN WhseMst
    ON WhseMst.WhseLink = PostST.WarehouseID
FULL JOIN _etblLotTracking
    ON _etblLotTracking.idLotTracking = PostST.iLotID

WHERE 
PostST.TrCodeID IN (34, 30) AND  StkItem.ItemGroup <> 'TRAN'
```

This query is run from Sage Evolution and data is dumped into Excel. From there I manipulate to view each item and the sales history in quantity per month and year.

My problem is as follows:

Within the data that follows, is sometimes a customer who has perhaps stopped buying a particular item. What I need is for this statement to also filter out a line by the following condition:

If the customer does not have a sale for 6 months or more, then that STOCK ITEM must be filtered out for that specific customer.

Thank you!

Comment: Please prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data and desired result. It will be much easier to provide accurate answer.

Comment: Hi @lad2025 I have added a screen shot of how the data lists with the current STATEMENT. What I need is, if say custommer Mister Sweet has not bought ITEM Licorice in 6 months or more, it must not show that LINE.

Comment: This is a simple matter of programming.   Do you know about the EXISTS() function in SQL that can be used in a WHERE clause?   If not, please google and learn about it.

Comment: First off all please do not post actual data (client name, financial, ...), it is very unprofessional.  Second demo (with dummy data) will be more helpful than image.

Comment: @TabAlleman I am not aware of it no, but I'll go give it some research on Google and see if the function assists. Thanks